# split images from array

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am getting links from a database and want to display the images but break line every 5 images. i can display images but need help,  I'm sure its an if statement but don't know how to write it. i need to display

image1,image2,image3,image4,image5 break
image6,image7,image8,image9,image10 break

and so on, i have  a total  of  100 images

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

$query = "SELECT *  FROM `image`";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$pics = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$pics[] = "\"".$row['src']."\"";
}

foreach($pics as $show){
echo "<img src=".$show.">";
}
?>
```

Comment: `<img style='display: inline-block;' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = 1;
foreach($pics as $show){
if($count < 6)
{
echo '<img src="'.$show.'">';
$count++;

}
else
{
echo '<br><img src="'.$show.'">';
$count = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Did that work for you? Go ahead and mark it as answered to close the question if it did

Comment: yes it worked for me, but wont let me select answered,  dont have enough rep,but its answered

Answer (score 2):

You can use another variable to count the entries

```
$count=0;
foreach($pics as $show){
  echo "<img src=".$show.">";
  if( $count % 5 == 0 ) echo "<br>";
  $count++;
}
```